# Como pegar JavaScript Dinâmico de outro site?

Tags: javascript

Dependendo da URL que uso, os dados oriundos do JavaSscript mudam.

Se eu utilizar a url: `meusite.com/jogador/123`, o JavaScript irá trazer os dados desse jogador 123, se eu alterar o jogador 123 para 456, o JavaScript abaixo trará as estatísticas do jogador 456.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var imp_careerStats = [
{
"id": "0c8d010d-9d47-4f10-805e-544ae89996b9",
"playerId": "67059891",
"mode": 4,
"type": 2,
"lastUpdated": "2019-06-09T17:00:51.7847614Z",
"kills": {
  "value": 1,
  "key": "Kills",
  "percentile": 92.0,
  "displayName": "Kills",
  "displayType": "Number",
  "category": "Combat",
  "columnName": "kills",
  "displayValue": "1",
  "displayPercentile": "Top 8%"
},...
</script>
```

Como eu consigo transformar esse JavaScript em JSON?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito confusa, tente melhorá-la.

Comment: veja se ficou melhor pra você agora. O que eu preciso é pegar os dados desse javascript que está em outro site e poder usar-lo, o ideal é coloca-lo como json

Comment: Vem com a tag `<script type="text/javascript">` e tudo?

Comment: sim, vem completo, copiei e colei o exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `JSON.parse()`, mas é preciso remover tudo o que não for objeto da string, como as tags `<script>` e os delimitadores de array `[` e `]` (ou `];`, o ponto e vírgula após o fechamento da array, se houver).

Para isso você pode utilizar o `.replace()` com uma expressão regular que retira tudo que for tag da string, a declaração da array e seus colchetes delimitadores, ficando apenas o objeto:

```js
// "data" seria o retorno em forma de string
var data = `
<script type="text/javascript">var imp_careerStats = [
{
"id": "0c8d010d-9d47-4f10-805e-544ae89996b9",
"playerId": "67059891",
"mode": 4,
"type": 2,
"lastUpdated": "2019-06-09T17:00:51.7847614Z",
"kills": {
  "value": 1,
  "key": "Kills",
  "percentile": 92.0,
  "displayName": "Kills",
  "displayType": "Number",
  "category": "Combat",
  "columnName": "kills",
  "displayValue": "1",
  "displayPercentile": "Top 8%"
}
}];
<\/script>`;

var json = data.replace(/<[^>]*>?|var imp_careerStats = \[|\](;)?/g, '').trim();
json = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas como faço isso se o javascript está em um site externo que eu não sou o proprietário?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: eu não tenho acesso ao site que contem o javascript, então como copio esse javascript externo?

Comment: Aí eu já não sei. Baseei a resposta no que vc informou na pergunta, dizendo que recebe o script em forma de string.